# How to change a Kubernetes pod tcp_keepalive

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, tcp-keepalive

I would like to change the default tcp keep alive value in a Kubernetes pod, what's the recommended approach?

Comment: Is the question about pure Docker, or Kubernetes?  The answer will be very different.

Comment: It is an Azure kubernetes Container

Answer (score 2):

You could do this via sysctls on the pod manifest in AKS/Kubernetes:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: "net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time"
      value: "45"
```

Here is also further documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/

https://docs.syseleven.de/metakube/de/tutorials/confiugre-unsafe-sysctls

Comment: the syseleven link is dead